# How to overwrite an old commit with another-branch's commit?

Tags: git

I have three commits on `master branch`:

```
master- 3st commit

master- 2st commit

master- 1st commit
```

Now I need to do some changes to `master- 2st commit`. So I checkout a new branch named `dev` from `master- 2st commit`. 
After doing some changes on branch `dev`, I do the commit `dev- 1st commit`.

I want to overwrite `master- 2st commit`with `dev- 1st commit`. 
Any advice on it? Thanks advance

Comment: `2st` and `3st` should be `2nd` and `3rd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to add new commits to `master`, you need to rewrite `master- 2nd commit` and `master-3rd commit`.

```
git checkout master

# rewrite <master- 2nd commit>
git reset <dev- 1st commit> --hard
git reset <master- 2nd commit> --soft
git commit --amend

# rewrite <master- 3rd commit>
git cherry-pick <master- 3rd commit>
```

The history will be like:

```
master- new 3rd commit
master- new 2nd commit
master- 1st commit
```

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING:** git history rewriting is almighty as long as no `git push` has been made. After that, you can still do everything you want, but that involves a force push that you should avoid.

The best way is to use `cherry-pick` in the following process:

```
git checkout master~2
git cherry-pick master~1
[make your edits]
git add --all
git commit --amend
git cherry-pick master
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

Explanations:

1. Place your `HEAD` on the commit located 2 commits before `master`.
2. Make a copy of the commit located 1 commit before `master` and append it after `HEAD`.
3. The edits you are going to do will be from the "2nd commit" point of view.
4. Add your edits to be commited.
5. Commit them, but instead of creating a new commit, you edit the previous one.
6. Copy the `master` commit after the `HEAD` location.
7. Checkout to the old `master` location.
8. Change the location of the branch to the previous location of `HEAD` (i.e. where you were before the last checkout: your new "3rd commit" commit).

**[Interactive demo](https://learngitbranching.js.org/?NODEMO&command=git%20commit;git%20checkout%20master~2;git%20cherry-pick%20master~1;echo%20%22Make%20some%20edits%22;git%20commit%20--amend;git%20cherry-pick%20master;git%20branch%20tmp;git%20checkout%20master;git%20reset%20--hard%20tmp;git%20branch%20-d%20tmp)** (that doesn't know about `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`, so it uses a temporary branch instead).

Answer (score 0):

Git is a toolbox where there are multiple tools to do the same job. I will approach this problem in this way -

Note commit id of `master- 3rd commit` with the help of `git log -1 --oneline` on master.

**Steps:**

```
git Checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~2
git cherry-pick <dev- 1st commit>
git cherry-pick <master- 3rd commit>
```

**Explanation:**

Assuming there are 3 commits on master, `git reset --hard HEAD~2` will detatch top two commits [3rd and 2nd] from 1st commit, branch master is now pointing to 1st commit.

`git cherry-pick <dev- 1st commit>` will add a new commit same as dev- 1st commit to master, branch master now points to the new dev commit.

`git cherry-pick <master- 3rd commit>` will again add a new commit on top of dev commit and now, history will look like -

```
master- new 3rd commit
dev - new 1st commit
master- old 1st commit
```